# /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname for FreeIPA on EC2

Tags: freeipa

I'm having issues on what to define on the following files:

/etc/hosts
/etc/hostname

The hostname contains the private hostname, while the hosts contains both mapping of the private and public IP. I'm having issues when accessing the web sicne it always redirects to the private IP.

Comment: Please ask about your problem, not for guides.

Comment: I see, apologies, my real problem is that, when I acess the web ui for the IPA, it always redirects to the private hostname and not the public dns.